# Замыкание или ловушка замыкания С#

Tags: c#

Не могу понять что делает этот кусок кода. Можете объяснить?

```
var list = new List<Action>();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));

foreach (var func in list)
    func();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Данный код:

1. Добавляет в список ссылки на вызов анонимной функции (лямбда)
2. Вызывает сохранённые в списке анонимные функции (лямбды)

"Проблема замыкания" тут в том, что аргументы функции тоже сохраняются по ссылке и при вызове этих функций получается, что каждая вызывается с одним и тем же аргументом - последним значением переменной `i` после окончания цикла. Как-то так.

Comment: не могла понять, почему выводит одни пятерки. теперь все поняла, благодарю!

Comment: Классическая ошибка в понимании захвата переменных лямбдами.

Comment: @aepot Ваш комментарий означает, что я прав или что я не прав? Непонятно :)

Comment: Мой комментарий не относится к вашему ответу, это скорее рефлексия на вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Хорошо. А то я уж думаю вдруг я чего не знаю. )  Так то да

Comment: _аргументы функции_ - тут несколько не корректно использованы, скорее _замыкаемые переменные_ или _внешние переменные используемые внутри функции_

Answer (score 5):

Действительно, захват внешних (для лямбда выражения) переменных осуществляется «по ссылке», это означает, что переменная i исчезает из стека и становится полем специально сгенерированного класса, в который затем помещается и тело анонимного метода.

Интересно отметить, что начиная с С# 5 вот такое выражение (ваш код c использованием `foreach`):

```
var list = new List<Action>();

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 5))
    list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));

foreach (var func in list)
    func();
```

Выдаст *предсказуемый* результат

```
1
2
3
```

Начиная с пятой версии языка переменная в цикле `foreach` создаётся заново при каждой итерации. Следовательно для того, чтобы получить результат `1 2 3` в предыдущих языках с `foreach` или в любой версии с `for` нужно просто создать переменную внутри цикла:

```
var list = new List<Action>();

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var temp = i;
    list.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(temp));
}

foreach (var func in list)
    func();
```