# Работает не так как ожидалось C# Threading

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Код готов к запуску. Возвращает не то что ожидается. Ожидается двумерный в первом уровне многомерного. Но работает только с костылём и возвращает немного не то. Я думаю по коду больше видно что я хотел. В отладчике будет неожиданный выход заграницы objArray без костыля.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace MyProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int[] arr = { 4, 5, 6, 2 };
            int[] arr2 = { 4, 5, 6, 2 };

            int n = 2;
            int step = arr.Length / n;

            // Создаем массив для хранения результатов обработки каждой части массива
            
            int[][][] objArray = new int[n][][];// ЕСЛИ ЗАМЕНИТЬ ТУТ n НА n+1 ТО РАБОТАЕТ, НО 
            // НА ВЫХОДЕ ОБЬЕКТ С ТРЕМЯ ЭЛЕМЕНТАМИ ВМЕСТО 2

            // Создаем потоки для каждой части массива и запускаем их параллельно
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[n];
            for (int pIndex = 0; pIndex < n; pIndex++)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(pIndex);
                int startIdx = pIndex * step;
                int endIdx = (pIndex + 1) * step - 1;
                threads[pIndex] = new Thread(() => {
                    // Выполняем операции над текущей частью массива
                    int[][] result = DoSomething();
                    // Сохраняем результат в массив результатов
                    objArray[pIndex] = result; 

                });
                threads[pIndex].Start();
            }

            // Ждем завершения всех потоков
            foreach (Thread thread in threads)
            {
                thread.Join();
            }


            static int[][] DoSomething(){
                int[][] numbers = new int[3][];
                numbers[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
                numbers[1] = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
                numbers[2] = new int[] { 8, 9 };
                return numbers;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А сделайте `Console.WriteLine(pIndex);` **внутри** потока. Я подозреваю, что внутрь потока попадает **ссылка** на переменную `pIndex`, в результате чего некоторые потоки получают значение `pIndex`, которое получается уже после завершения цикла, т.е. `pIndex = n`. Почитайте про **замыкание**. Например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1206904/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%A1

Comment: Судя по содержимому отладчика они так и есть. И при этом они ещё и с задержкой начинают поступать. Нулевой элемент в результате пустой. Результаты уже в следующих. Осталось понять как это всё работает...

Comment: Ну, я вам дал ссылку. Либо гуглите по словам "замыкания C#". Ну или вот ещё ссылка: https://habr.com/ru/articles/141270/

Comment: Удалось разобраться?

Comment: Да. Мне помогли исправить код.  Уже хотел просто переписать без замыканий. Понимание ещё впереди.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива `objArray`, который еще не был инициализирован. В данном случае вы создаете массив `objArray` с размером n, но каждый элемент этого массива должен быть инициализирован как двумерный массив. Однако, вы не инициализируете каждый элемент массива `objArray` как двумерный массив.
Вы можете инициализировать каждый элемент `objArray` при создании массива, как показано ниже:

```
int[][][] objArray = new int[n][][];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    objArray[i] = new int[3][];
}
```

Это создаст массив `objArray` с n элементами, каждый из которых будет инициализирован как двумерный массив размером 3 на n (т.е. каждый элемент будет представлять собой 3 строки и n столбцов).
Затем, внутри цикла, вы можете сохранять результат `DoSomething` в соответствующий элемент `objArray`:

```
threads[pIndex] = new Thread(() => {
    // Выполняем операции над текущей частью массива
    int[][] result = DoSomething();
    // Сохраняем результат в массив результатов
    objArray[pIndex] = result; 
});
```

Теперь вы можете получить доступ к результатам, сохраненным в `objArray`, вне цикла потока. Например, вы можете вывести все элементы `objArray` на консоль следующим образом:

```
foreach (int[][] array2D in objArray)
{
    foreach (int[] array1D in array2D)
    {
        foreach (int num in array1D)
        {
            Console.Write(num + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

UP

```
        int[] arr = { 4, 5, 6, 2 };
        int[] arr2 = { 4, 5, 6, 2 };

        int n = 2;
        int step = arr.Length / n;

        int[][][] objArray = new int[n][][];

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[n];
        for (int pIndex = 0; pIndex < n; pIndex++)
        {
            int currentIndex = pIndex; // Создаем временную переменную
            Console.WriteLine(pIndex);
            int startIdx = currentIndex * step;
            int endIdx = (currentIndex + 1) * step - 1;
            threads[currentIndex] = new Thread(() => {
                int[][] result = DoSomething();
                objArray[currentIndex] = result; // Используем временную переменную
            });
            threads[currentIndex].Start();
        }

        // Ждем завершения всех потоков
        foreach (Thread thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }


        static int[][] DoSomething(){
            int[][] numbers = new int[3][];
            numbers[0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
            numbers[1] = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 };
            numbers[2] = new int[] { 8, 9 };
            return numbers;
        }
```

Попробуй так.

Comment: Не помогло. Я конечно ещё проверю, но пока что поведение не поменялось.

Comment: @Slava32768 скорректировал проверь

Comment: Да. Работает. Очень помогло. Вникаю как.